# fatal error: boost/chrono.hpp: No such file or directory

Tags: c++, boost

This question has been asked many times in different ways, but none of the solutions have  solved my problem.

Environment : Ubuntu 12.04, Eclipse-cdt

1. Boost library 1.55.0 (thread, chrono, date_time and system) is at **/boost**
2. Included the same path in Project Properties -> C/C++ General -> Paths and Symbols -> Includes -> Include directories
3. Included **/boost/stage/lib** in Project Properties -> C/C++ General -> Paths and Symbols -> Includes -> Library Paths
4. Linked all libraries e.g. **/boost/stage/lib/libboost_chrono.a** in **_LDADDS**
5. Used **-I** in **_CPPFLAGS** to give **/boost** header files

Am I missing something?

Comment: Huh. _What_ is at **/boost**? That's completely unclear.

Comment: @sehe That's installation directory. I have installed only those four libraries.

Comment: How? <padding/><padding/>

Comment: created `/boost` and extracted tar file to this directory. Then `sudo ./bootstrap.sh --with-libraries=thread,chrono,date_time,system --prefix=/usr/local` Afterwards `sudo ./b2` for installation